syntax .long 0xXXXX @ for 0xXXXX, ram
I'm trying to understand the assembly code given with the ARM GNAT compiler for a Zynq-7000.
In the linker script, I have the memory defined like this:
MEMORY
{
  SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 1M, LENGTH = 1022M
  UCSRAM (rw) : ORIGIN = 1023M, LENGTH = 1M
}

I think the UCSRAM is the "uncached SRAM" (but no documentation or comments can confirm this for me).
In the sections, I have this defined:
   .ucache (NOLOAD): {
     . = ALIGN(0x08);
     *(.ucache)
   } > UCSRAM

I have then a file called memmap.inc that is included in the assembly file, with this syntax:
__mmu_l0:
    .long 0x00017c0e  @ for 0x00000000, ram
    .long 0x00117c0e  @ for 0x00100000, ram
<...>
    .long 0x3ff10c06  @ for 0x3ff00000, ram-uc
    .long 0x00000000  @ for 0x40000000, *none*

Can you explained the syntax .long 0x00017c0e  @ for 0x00000000, ram? What ram and ram-uc symbols mean?
Thanks.

You are looking an MMU table.  The '@' is an assembler comment and has no meaning but what humans apply to it.  The MMU table is composed of bit fields as to properties of that entry.  Entries can point to other entries.  That is the '_l0' part.  It means this is a primary table (first level).  .long 0x00017c0e is just 32bit data, but to decode it, you must understand ARM mmu table fields.

The bits are slightly different for different CPU revisions, so it is somewhat dependant on the target system.  You can find the bit definitions for a particular CPU and/or google and find many tutorials/information on line.  It looks like they are (super) sections entries, which is mainly a flat map (with the exception of invalid 0x40000000).  Maybe this helps?
